# Is the word order in 我也在英國 and 你是很快速 and 你不真的在咖啡廳 correct?

Tags: grammar

I have a feeling what I'm writing is either wrong order or unnatural sounding. Can someone verify?

> 我也在英國

(I'm also in england)

> 你是很快速

(You are very fast)

> 你不真的在咖啡廳

(You arent really at the cafe.)

In these examples they feel correct to me, but the last one I am particularly unsure of, and also, in the second one, I suspect the 是 is unnecessary and makes it sound unnatural.

Comment: Please, write in English what do want to mean with the third sentence.

Comment: Im trying to say “you arent really at the cafe.” As in they said they are but it was not true.

Comment: That's better, but I really can't help you.

Comment: The 1st one is fine. For the 2nd one you can remove the "是", i.e. "你很快"; For the 3rd one you can add the "是", i.e. "你不是真的在咖啡厅", to make them sound more natural.

Comment: @HenryKingston 英國 is the UK, not England (which is 英格蘭); you might offend some people if you don't differentiate the two. Also, use 咖啡「廳」for cafe.

Comment: @droooze who would be offended? Chinese speaking Northern Irelanders?

Answer (score 3):

First sentence is good. For the second, "快速" is more commonly used as a adverb not an adjective, so you can say "这辆车可以快速地移动" but usually not "这辆车很快速". Also I would omit the "是". So instead of "你是很快速" I would say "你很快".
As for the last one "你不是真的在咖啡厅" would sound more natural.

Answer (score 0):

我也在英國 → correct  . To make it more natural and lovely you can add （呢/哦/哟/呀） at the end of the sentence, a.e. **我也在英國呢。**
你是很快速 → 你真快/你好快. To make it more natural you can add （啊/呀/哦） at the end of the sentence, a.e. **你好快呀。**
你不真的在咖啡聽 → 你（才）不（是）在咖啡厅/你（才）没（有）在咖啡厅, if you use the complete forms, you can add （呢） at then end of the sentence, a.e **你才不是在咖啡厅呢。**